# How to include the missing URLs in the sitemap

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

I am trying to generate sitemap.xml for an eCommerce website from xml-sitemaps.com
All the URLs are being scanned but the footer links of the website are missing in the xml file.
The whole website is written in javascript except the foooters which are in wordpress and these footer links are redirects from an old website.

Answer (score 0):

The crawler from xml-sitemaps.com skips pages that are redirected (as well as pages that have a canonical meta tag pointing to a different URL).

You should still see them in the log from your last - they would have been discovered, but ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you please suggest any way I can create a sitemap which includes those redirects?